# RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to solve an `nlp` problem where i am using `pytorch`.here i am using `sklearn's` `StratifiedKFold` module for `cross_validation`, in which got a runtime error during looping through `folds`.

**error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-f1ccf940359e> in <module>
----> 1 oof_train(ds, cv, y, epochs = EPOCHES)

<ipython-input-42-eaeaa91076bd> in oof_train(ds, cv, y, epochs)
     14     loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
     15 
---> 16     for fold, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(cv.split(range(len(ds)), y)):
     17 
     18         train_ds = D.Subset(ds, train_idx)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
    729         to an integer.
    730         """
--> 731         y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    732         return super().split(X, y, groups)
    733 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    614                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    615                 else:
--> 616                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    617             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    618                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    628             return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__array__, relevant_args, self, dtype=dtype)
    629         if dtype is None:
--> 630             return self.numpy()
    631         else:
    632             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.
```

**piece of code where it showing errors**

```
def oof_train(ds, cv, y, epochs = EPOCHES):

   loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    
    for fold, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(cv.split(range(len(ds)), y)):
        
        train_ds = D.Subset(ds, train_idx)
        loader = D.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                              shuffle=True, collate_fn = collate_fn,num_workers=0)
        
        valid_ds = D.Subset(ds, valid_idx)
        vloader = D.DataLoader(valid_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                      shuffle=False, collate_fn = collate_fn,num_workers=0)
```

**code where i initialize StratifiedKFold**

```
df_size = train_csv.shape[0]
num_bins = int(np.floor(1 + np.log2(df_size)))
# bin targets
y = pd.cut(train_csv["target"], bins=num_bins, labels=False)

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=N_FOLDS, shuffle=True, random_state=SEED)
```

**code where i create dataset:**

```
class LitDataset(D.Dataset):

    def __init__(self,token,meta,target):
        self.token = token
        self.meta = meta
        self.target = target
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.token)
    
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        return torch.tensor(self.token[idx].input_ids),torch.tensor(self.token[idx].attention_mask),\
                self.meta[idx],self.target[idx]


def collate_fn(batch):
    ids,attns,meta,targets = zip(*batch)
    ids = pad_sequence(ids, batch_first=True, padding_value=tokenizer.pad_token_id).to(DEVICE)
    attns = pad_sequence(attns, batch_first=True,padding_value=tokenizer.pad_token_id).to(DEVICE)
    meta =torch.tensor(meta).to(DEVICE)
    targets = torch.tensor(targets).float().to(DEVICE)
    return ids,attns,meta,targets

ds = LitDataset(train_csv_stat.token.values,train_meta_features,train_y.values)
```

Comment: please try `for fold, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(cv.split(range(len(ds)), y.cpu())):` If this works I'll write an answer

Comment: thanks @Gulzar i tried this but it did not work.

Comment: still getting same error at the same line.

Comment: what is the 'ds' you are passing to the 'oof_train' function?
where do you instantiate it?

Comment: oops sorry please use `for fold, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(cv.split(range(len(ds)), y.detach().numpy()))`